# Python Tornado Facebook Auth Error

Tags: python, tornado, facebook-login

I am using python tornado 4.1. I am trying facebook login from their demos but it throws error. I put screenshoot for the error.

The Error :

```
AuthError: Facebook auth error: HTTPResponse(_body=None,buffer=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x29f0290>,code=400,effective_url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_secret=&code=&client_id=&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsoctag.com%2F%2Fauth%2Ffacebooklogin',error=HTTPError('HTTP 400: Bad Request',),headers={'Content-Length': '190', 'Facebook-Api-Version': 'v1.0', 'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'X-Fb-Debug': 'fKw1RAojsZPT2jl7ErDX4S6c2ROg8TgV1KqFn3Yexc9jgJetmP4K0nFZTrATG7cH5ESLJZ51HyACUJQszv5Fmw==', 'X-Fb-Rev': '1685640', 'Connection': 'close', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store', 'Date': 'Mon, 13 Apr 2015 11:18:34 GMT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8', 'Www-Authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"'},reason='Bad Request',request=<tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest object at 0x2a2edd0>,request_time=0.5871150493621826,time_info={})
```

Scrrenshoot
[image]

The code :

```
class AuthFacebookLoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument("code", False):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(
              redirect_uri=Helper.url('/auth/facebooklogin'),
              client_id=self.settings["facebook_api_key"],
              client_secret=self.settings["facebook_secret"],
              code=self.get_argument("code"))

            self.redirect("/auth/facebookmain")
        else:
            yield self.authorize_redirect(
                redirect_uri=Helper.url('/auth/facebooklogin'),
                client_id=self.settings["facebook_api_key"],
                extra_params={"scope": "read_stream"})


class AuthFacebookMainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        new_entry = yield self.facebook_request(
            "/me/feed",
            post_args={"message": "I am posting from my Tornado application!"},
            access_token=self.current_user["access_token"])

        if not new_entry:
            # Call failed; perhaps missing permission?
            yield self.authorize_redirect()
            return
        self.finish("Posted a message!")
```

Comment: Might wanna make that error a little bigger, or actually put the text in your question, or something.

Comment: @DonkeyKong i also put the error as text

Answer (score 1):

Your error message has the clue:

> Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in
>   the OAuth dialog request

Check to make sure your url is the same as configured in Facebook.
Your site url in the Facebook configuration page under basic settings must be the same as the url for your page.

If you are testing from localhost, You can change your /etc/hosts to map your testing domain to 127.0.0.1.

Don't forget that inside Facebook you can create testing versions of your app that have different configurations.

I typically have at least a production, testing and development version.